# What is this white fibrous thing showing on top of moist soil?

Tags: identification, soil, germination, water

I'm trying to germinate chives using a soil for seeds. I've gone through the process of watering and draining the soil after putting in the seeds. For two days now, I've been seeing this cloudy spongy thing on top of the soil.

Is this perhaps something to do with excess moisture?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

These are fungal mycelium who like high humidity and low air movement.  Manually remove the issue and vent the pot for a few hours a day.

Not a serious problem and not toxic to you or the seeds.

Comment: Might even be a positive to development of seedlings. This mycelium will reduce in a few days and go mostly below the soil.

Comment: @rockerBOO Possibly, but at a possible cost in ease of germination. I always choose seeds first